# Load HTML from applicationDirectory in TideSDK

Tags: javascript, html, tidesdk

I'm using the default `index.html` located in `RessourcesFolder` of my app. The `index.html` page is only there to check if my application has an update (new html pages to display in app).

It works perfectly.. I can download my new contents from the server in `applicationDataDirectory`

But.. when I finished the application update, I'd like to replace the current `index.html` page with my `updateindex.html`

Loading remote html pages works fine, for example:

```
currentWindow.setURL('http://www.stackoverflow.com/' );
```

However, when I try something like

```
currentWindow.setURL('C:\Documents and Settings\myuser\Application Data\TideSDK\testApp\index_update.html' );
```

Nothing is appended..

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

you can modify the path of which index page you want to load within your application

this can be modified within the tiapp.xml file. Replace "app://index.html" with "app://updateindex.html" and you should be good to go